# Sequelize and MySQL associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, associations

I'm working with Sequelize, MySQL and NodeJS. I'm trying to have 3 tables associated which are laid out as follows:

```
products
product_id
name
description

product_tags
product_id
tag_id

tag_names
tag_id 
tag_name
```

I want to associate products with the tags table and then from there whatever the tag name is associated with the tag_id. Like the following:

```
SELECT 
name, 
a.product_id,
group_concat(b.tag_id) as tags,
group_concat(tag_name) as tagName
FROM products a
JOIN product_tags b on b.product_id = a.product_id
JOIN tag_names c on c.tag_id = b.tag_id
WHERE name
```

Which would then return the product name, tags etc. 
I'm just struggling to understand how this works regarding hasMany, belongsTo etc.
My current code is:

```
db.products.hasMany(db.product_tags, {foreignKey: 'product_id'});

db.product_tags.belongsTo(db.products, {foreignKey: 'product_id'});
db.product_tags.hasMany(db.tag_names, {foreignKey: 'tag_id'});

db.tag_names.belongsTo(db.product_tags, {foreignKey: 'tag_id'});
```

Which seems to return the correctly laid out tables, but I can't insert a new tag into the tag_name table without it throwing a foreign key error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Danny

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this answer with the same question I figured it out:

```
db.products.belongsToMany(db.tag_names, { through: 'product_tags',  as: "tags", foreignKey: 'product_id'});
db.tag_names.belongsToMany(db.products, {through: 'product_tags',  as: "products", foreignKey: 'tag_id'});
```

Solves the problem.